State rights regulating traffic safety
The increasing weight and height of passenger vehicles puts others at risk during side-impact collisions, as well as at risk due to  disparity between large heavy passenger-truck EVs and small efficient sub-compacts.
Could say a progressive state, California or New York, ban registration of vehicles over a certain weight? Could these states require a CDL for vehicles over a certain weight, regardless if classified as passenger vehicles?


Could these states require a CDL for vehicles over a certain weight, regardless if classified as passenger vehicles?

States can absolutely regulate based on the vehicles weight and require different classes of driving license based on that. States generally regulate classes of vehicles based on Gross Vehicle Weight Rating (GVWR) or Max Authorized Mass (MAM). Both mean the total weight of the vehicle, including the vehicle itself and everything it carries. It doesn't matter how heavy the driver is, or how obese the passenger is, and whether they're carrying a load of gold bars or cotton candy. What matters is how much the vehicle weighs in total.
In California, for example, class C license is sufficient for vehicles with GVWR below 26000 lbs. Similarly, EU class B license is sufficient for vehicles with MAM of 3500kg or lower. International Driver Permit classifications are similar to the EU classifications.
For comparison, Tesla Cybertruck (a heavy passenger-truck EV) has GVWR of about 9600lbs, which is about 4350kg. That makes the Cybertruck allowable under the CA C license, but not allowable under the EU B license.

As mentioned in the comments, CDL (Commercial Driver License) is regulated Federally. However, the gist of your question is "whether states can require different licenses for different classes of cars", and the answer to that is yes.
A good example would be RVs. In California, RV over 40' long would require a different type of license than a regular passenger car - class B (see the same link as above). That would apply even for personal use, while for commercial use of a similarly sized vehicle (e.g.: bus driver) a CDL would be required.

This said, there are federal vehicle standards and there is the dormant commerce clause. States that want to continue to receive highway funds (upon which every U.S. state is quite dependent) have significant boundaries on what they can do. "Could say a progressive state, California or New York, ban registration of vehicles over a certain weight?" Probably not, if it is legal under federal law at least up to a point (some state level variation in regulation of multi-trailer semis is allowed).

That's for licensing. The Federal FMVSS regulations preempt state regulation of new motor vehicle design/equipment. This recently happened in California regarding some lights. Conversely, some states allow registration of vehicles that are prohibited by FMVSS, stuff like ATVs and golf carts.

@user71659 the second part of the OP's question is about licensing.

Let's look at that. "Could these states require a CDL for vehicles over a certain weight" A CDL is a license set federally by FMCSA by the Commercial Motor Vehicle Safety Act of 1986 under the Dominant Commerce Clause. Because Congress has limited powers for intrastate commerce and non-commercial operation, it does not apply to either. One example: varying driving ages for normal licenses. So, no a CDL could not and is not required for private vehicle operation or intrastate commerce.

@user71659 It is the "dormant commerce clause" not the "dominant commerce clause". https://constitution.congress.gov/browse/essay/artI-S8-C3-7-1/ALDE_00013307/

@user71659 added to the answer.

@user71659 Did not even think about a new 18 yr old driver in a Cyber Truck...wow...
